# Generate variance estimates using a loop

Tags: r, loops, variance

My question:

- Calculate a sample of 3 observations on a `N (1,12)` variable.
- Use the sample to calculate `s^2` and `variance` estimate .
- Repeat the operation 10000 times and use the estimates to verify that `E[s^2-var] < E[ variance estimate- var]`

I know the variance equations:

> sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(n-1) it the equation for (sample variance)
>
> sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(n+1) is the equation for (variance estimate)

Generating, the 3 observations is half the problem!
I think this will suffices

```
rnorm(3,1,12)
```

therefore

```
x <- rnorm(3,1,12)
```

Creating function:

```
 s2fun <- function(n){
 s2 <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(n-1)
 s2
 }
```

Creating Loops:

```
A <- matrix(0,10000,1)

for (i in 1:10000){
    n <- i
    A[i,] <- s2fun(n)
}
```

But everytime I check (A) it generates the 10000 results removing the script from reach

even with

> sum(A)/n
>   resulting in inf.

Comment: As this looks like coursework, it would be beneficial if you could make some efforts. So please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for editing. You are almost there, just a couple of points: your `s2fun` function is not quite right - you should pass `x` as the argument, and estimate `n` using the  `length` of `x`. I would write it as `s2fun <- function(x){  sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1) }`.  As you want  repeat sampling , you need to include a new `rnorm` call for each iteration of the loop: so id write - `for (i in 1:10000){ A[i,] <- s2fun(rnorm(3, 1, 12))} ` .

Comment: Lastly, a minor comment, you do not need to store the values in a matrix, you could just use a vector: so initialise `A <- numeric(10000)`, and then use `A[i]` in the loop. [ps as one alternative, that still uses loops you could use `B = replicate(10000, s2fun(rnorm(3, 1, 12)))`]